# Angular UI router loads wrong controller/template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Maybe it's something simple, but this is the first time I'm using the [angular-ui-router](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/). I'm using html5 mode and I've got the following states configured:

```
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $authProvider.loginUrl = API_LOCATION + 'authenticate';

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/auth');
    
    $stateProvider
        .state('auth', {
            url: '/auth',
            templateUrl: TEMPLATES_LOCATION + 'login.html',
            controller: 'AuthController as auth'
        })
        .state('country', {
            url: '/country',
            templateUrl: TEMPLATES_LOCATION + 'country.index.html',
            controller: 'CountryListController'
        })
        .state('country.select', {
            url: '/select',
            templateUrl: TEMPLATES_LOCATION + 'country.select.html',
            controller: 'CountrySelectController'
        })
        .state('country.edit', {
            url: '/:isoCode',
            templateUrl: TEMPLATES_LOCATION + 'country.edit.html',
            controller: 'CountryEditController'
        });
```

All country routes load `country.index.html` and `CountryEditController`. Why?

## EDIT

my .htaccess file (the angular app is in a subfolder named "admin")

```
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteBase /admin/ <- tried this too

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /admin/index.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Have you tried `MYSITEURL/#/country` ?

Comment: I'm using html5 mode, forgot to mention that.

Comment: You need to add an htaccess to your server (url rewriting) to make it working

Comment: I am sure if you do `<a ui-sref="country">Country Link</a>` it will work

Comment: Question updated, maybe by .htaccess is not configured well. Btw your second comment doesn't solve the issue on browser page refresh (which is a common user action).

Comment: have you tried the things by commenting the `htaccess` and html5 for the time being

Comment: Removed the .htaccess file, disabled html5mode, and the url is `http://localhost:8003/admin/#/country`. Same result.

Comment: have you added a `base` tag to your html's HEAD element?

Comment: Yup, `<base href="/admin/">`

Comment: And do you have an extra `<div ui-view></div>` element on the **country.index.html** view file for the child states?

Comment: Isn't that required for child views? Cause select and edit are completely different pages with controllers, not boxes inside the country.index template.

Comment: Yes, because they are nested, so unless you're using [named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) I think that you need to add the above tag at the bottom of your HTML (just try it, maybe i'm wrong, but AFAIK this is how it should work)

Comment: Nope, still showing the index template and running the edit controller.